Reference cells keep changing in formula. Struggling with combining averaging, ifs and indirect functions in one
I've seen some similar posts recommending the use of index and Indirect function for problems similar to mine. I'm taking my issue a step further and am hoping for input!
My problem is that I need to take averages of column E, F and G in blocks of 10 or 30. Getting my data to be in nice columns takes a little sorting to have consistent positioning on this sheet that I can do by deleting blank/useless rows. The way the data is generated is inconsistent and needs to always be used the same way.
Input Data
My issue is trying to compile these from this now consistent data layout. My other sheet that references these continuously changes when I move anything on this sheet by deleting rows.
This is the formula I am using on my output sheet for one output. This then repeats a few dozen times with continuous blocks of data. ie:
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(Data!E$4:E$13),#N/A)

=IFERROR(AVERAGE(Data!E$14:E$23),#N/A)

=IFERROR(AVERAGE(Data!E$24:E$53),#N/A)

I need to average data always in Rows E4:E13, E14:23, etc. If the rows are empty, I need the cell to output #N/A to avoid being graphed.
I'm struggling to combine these multiple formulas with an indirect function to get it to stop referencing other cells when I organize my input data on the data sheet. I'm not sure If I can use the data pts column I created in K to help.
Please let me know if anything needs to be clarified. I am using office 2021.  Thanks for any input!

=IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDEX(Data!E:E,4):INDEX(Data!E:E,13)),#N/A)?

If you add a $ in front of either the row or column, you fixate them into the formula, and they won't change. So =IFERROR(Average(Data!$E$24:$E$53),#N/A) should be what you need.

Indexing worked perfectly. Unfortunately, using the $ doesn't help in this situation as a lot of the input data is moved around. The $ doesn't stop references moving when rows are deleted, inserted, dragged etc. Thank you both!

Paste this in the initial cell you want to reference to row 4:13 and drag down from there:
=IFERROR(AVERAGE(INDEX(Data!E:E,(ROW(A1)-1)*10+4):INDEX(Data!E:E,(ROW(A1)-1)*10+13)),NA())
Where (ROW(A1)-1)*10 will calculate as 0. Adding 4 (and 13) to 0 results in 4 (and 13).
If you drag it down one row (ROW(A2)-1)*10 will calculate as 10 (plus 4 equals 14; plus 13 equals 23), etc.
